# jQuery UI tabs, select/unselect (collapse) events

Tags: jquery, events, tabs, unselect

I am using jQuery UI 1.8.5 tabs plugin, with collapsible : true configuration.
I need to call a function after a tab is collapsed to add a css class. Does anyone know how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check if the `ui-tabs-selected` class exists on click.  Assuming you're using standard markup:

```
// in your click event
var selected_exists = $('#yourTabBox')
    .children('ul.ui-tabs-nav')
    .children('li.ui-tabs-selected')
    .length;

if (selected_exists) {
    // Nothing is collapsed
} else {
    // collapsed
}
```

This is perfect for the [`select`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#event-select) event.

Comment: @Stephen ... reckon he might show us what he's tried or something? `;)` ... sure would be nice to know what he's fighting huh?

Comment: @drachenstern: Agreed.  If what we've described doesn't work, we'll need to see some examples of what has been tried, along with some markup.

Comment: Nice answer (+1 if I had any votes left!).  Just to note that within the `select` event, `this` is outer div element, so your code could be reduced to `$(this).children('ul.ui-tabs-nav > li.ui-tabs-selected').length`.  Slightly quicker & more flexible.

Comment: This works, I have seen another question for this and the answer was similar, this solution seems like a work around instead of a solid event triggering eg. 'collapsed'. Anyway thanks guys!

Comment: actually, this almost worked, but problem is, you cannot really depends on the class since it applies "ui-tabs-selected" AFTER the select event

Comment: @James Lin: You can use `if (1 === $(this).find('ul.ui-tabs-nav > li.ui-tabs-selected').length)` This will pass if you're collapsing the tabs and fail if you're expanding them.  That should be sufficient for you, I think?

Comment: lol @ yoda condition : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349378/new-programming-jargon-you-coined/2430307#2430307

Comment: I have a work around for this class work around, hence marking it answered.

Comment: Remember I said you cannot check the class because select event fires before applying the class? In my scenario, I have a mouseout event, which I can use to check the class exists or not.

Answer (score 1):

What about the [show event](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#event-show) won't work for this? Because you don't know which one was hidden?

Maybe even the [select event](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#event-select) might be what you want.

using the ['tabsselect'](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#events) event:

```
$(".selector").tabs({
    collapsible: true,
    select: function(event, ui)
    {
         var prevSelectedIndex = $(".selector").tabs('option', 'selected');
         var nextSelectedIndex = ui.index;

         if(prevSelectedIndex === -1)
         {
             // It was previously collapsed and the user is now opening
             // tab at index: nextSelectedIndex 
         }
         else if(prevSelectedIndex === nextSelectedIndex )
         {
              // The user has clicked on the currently opened
              // tab and it is collapsing
         }
    }
});
```

Comment: I came across this issue and used your answer. I Added a code snippet to show how I used it for future reference.