# Collapse jquery tab when click outside of the div

Tags: jquery, tabs

I have a set of jQuery tabs and I have them collapsed by default. What I would like to do is to have them collapse when clicking outside of the div. Here is my code so far:

```
    <div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <p><strong>Click this tab again to close the content pane.</strong></p>
    <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <p><strong>Click this tab again to close the content pane.</strong></p>
    <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis. Sed fringilla, massa eget luctus malesuada, metus eros molestie lectus, ut tempus eros massa ut dolor. Aenean aliquet fringilla sem. Suspendisse sed ligula in ligula suscipit aliquam. Praesent in eros vestibulum mi adipiscing adipiscing. Morbi facilisis. Curabitur ornare consequat nunc. Aenean vel metus. Ut posuere viverra nulla. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellenter code hereentesque convallis. Maecenas feugiat, tellus pellentesque pretium posuere, felis lorem euismod felis, eu ornare leo nisi vel felis. Mauris consectetur tortor et purus.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
    <p><strong>Click this tab again to close the content pane.</strong></p>
    <p>Duis cursus. Maecenas ligula eros, blandit nec, pharetra at, semper at, magna. Nullam ac lacus. Nulla facilisi. Praesent viverra justo vitae neque. Praesent blandit adipiscing velit. Suspendisse potenti. Donec mattis, pede vel pharetra blandit, magna ligula faucibus eros, id euismod lacus dolor eget odio. Nam scelerisque. Donec non libero sed nulla mattis commodo. Ut sagittis. Donec nisi lectus, feugiat porttitor, tempor ac, tempor vitae, pede. Aenean vehicula velit eu tellus interdum rutrum. Maecenas commodo. Pellentesque nec elit. Fusce in lacus. Vivamus a libero vitae lectus hendrerit hendrerit.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

and here is my jquery:

```
$(function() {
$( "#tabs" ).tabs({
        selected: -1,
        collapsible: true,
});
})
```

I'm a jQuery noob so I'm sure this will be somewhat simple.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: easy?  you'd be surprised http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072745/jquery-ui-tabs-select-unselect-collapse-events  you might want to try a better ui before you get too deep

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
$(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
            selected: -1,
            collapsible: true,
    });
});

$('body').on('click', function(e){
    var target = $(e.target);
    if(!target.parents('#tabs').length){
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs('option', 'selected', -1);
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/qB32x/1/)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by binding to the `document`'s `click` event and collapsing the active tab by simulating a click on the active tab.

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
    // make sure the click is outside the tabs
    if($(e.target).parents('#tabs').length == 0) {
        $('#tabs ul li.ui-state-active a').trigger('click');
    }
});
```

Check this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SdfkD/

Answer (score 0):

Try this `jQuery UI` Instead of creating custom Accordian :

http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Comment: I'm sorry to have not mentioned it but I'm already using jquery ui

Answer (score 0):

It's not as straightforward as you might think.  In jQuery, you detect clicks for individual elements of the DOM, so to determine if someone has clicked *outside* of a given area, you would have to bind a click event to the entire body and then deal with the separate clickable areas individually.

(Binding a click to the entire body might not be the best idea speed-wise, so you may want to redesign the functionality of the tabs instead.  Does the tab really need to collapse when the user clicks anywhere outside it? or will just clicking on the same heading to collapse the tab work?  If so, go with @Dead Man's suggestion of a jQuery accordion.)  Assuming that you really do need to implement tabs in the manner you describe, you could try something like the following:

Using a modified version of your HTML:

```
<div id="tabs" >
  <div class"expander">Click to expand Tab1</div>
  <div class="tab-text">Here is the text that appears when Tab1 is expanded</div>
  <div class"expander">Click to expand Tab2</div>
  <div class="tab-text">Here is the text that appears when the Tab2 is expanded</div>
</div>
```

You would need some jQuery like this:

```
$( 'body' ).click( function( e ) {
  var $target = e.target;
  if( $target.is( '#tabs > .expander' ) ) {
    // We show a given tab when the user clicks on the heading to reveal it.
    $target.next().show();

    // You'll also need to decide what to do with the .expander itself.  
    // (You could change its text using .text( 'Click to hide' ) or you 
    // could just hide it until the user clicks outside all the tabs.

  } else if ( !( $target.is( '#tabs' ) || $target.is( '#tabs > div' ) ) ) {
    // If the user clicks outside of all the tabs, we hide them.
    $( '#tabs > .tab-text' ).hide();
  }

  // Add all other click event handlers for the page here.  
  if( $target.is( ...... ) ) {

  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own custom accordion:

```js
 $('.accordionOm').next().hide();
 $(".opened").next().show();
 $('.accordionOm').click(function()
 {
  if($(this).hasClass("opened") == true)
  {
   $(this).next().slideUp("slow");
   $(this).removeClass('opened');
  }
  else
  {
   $(".opened").next().slideUp("slow");
   $(".opened").removeClass("opened");
   $(this).addClass('opened');
   $(this).next().slideDown("slow");
  }
 });
```

```css
.accordionOm { position:relative; padding:10px 0 10px 30px; margin:0; font:300 18px 'Oswald', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; cursor:pointer;}
.accordionOm:hover { color:#000;}
.accordionOm:before,.accordionOm:after { content:""; position:absolute; background:#333; display:inline-block;}
.accordionOm:before { width:20px; height:2px; left:0; top:22px;}
.accordionOm:after { width:2px; height:20px; left:9px; top:13px; transition:transform .5s; transform:rotate(0);}
.accordionOm.opened:after { transform:rotate(90deg);}
.accordionOm + div { border-left:4px solid #999; padding:0 15px; margin-left:8px; font:13px 'Open Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#666;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4 class="accordionOm opened">Accordian heading</h4>
<div>
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, adipiscing elit. Nullam dignissim convallis est. Quisque aliquam. Donec faucibus. Nunc iaculis suscipit dui. Nam sit amet sem. Aliquam libero nisi, imperdiet at, tincidunt nec, gravida vehicula, nisl. Praesent mattis, massa quis luctus fermentum, turpis mi volutpat justo, eu volutpat enim diam eget metus.</p>
</div>

<h4 class="accordionOm">Accordian heading</h4>
<div>
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, adipiscing elit. Nullam dignissim convallis est. Quisque aliquam. Donec faucibus. Nunc iaculis suscipit dui. Nam sit amet sem. Aliquam libero nisi, imperdiet at, tincidunt nec, gravida vehicula, nisl. Praesent mattis, massa quis luctus fermentum, turpis mi volutpat justo, eu volutpat enim diam eget metus.</p>
</div>

<h4 class="accordionOm">Accordian heading</h4>
<div>
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, adipiscing elit. Nullam dignissim convallis est. Quisque aliquam. Donec faucibus. Nunc iaculis suscipit dui. Nam sit amet sem. Aliquam libero nisi, imperdiet at, tincidunt nec, gravida vehicula, nisl. Praesent mattis, massa quis luctus fermentum, turpis mi volutpat justo, eu volutpat enim diam eget metus.</p>
</div>

<h4 class="accordionOm">Accordian heading</h4>
<div>
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, adipiscing elit. Nullam dignissim convallis est. Quisque aliquam. Donec faucibus. Nunc iaculis suscipit dui. Nam sit amet sem. Aliquam libero nisi, imperdiet at, tincidunt nec, gravida vehicula, nisl. Praesent mattis, massa quis luctus fermentum, turpis mi volutpat justo, eu volutpat enim diam eget metus.</p>
</div>
```