# Touch not working on iPad with collapse tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, ipad

I have a collapsable tab bar, I wanted it so when I click anywhere on the page it collapses the tabs, I used the code below which works perfect. But, I cant get it to work on touch (iPads, iPhones, etc.)

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
    // make sure the click is outside the tabs
    if($(e.target).parents('#tabs').length == 0) {
        $('#tabs ul li.ui-state-active a').trigger('click');
    }
});
```

Any help will be great if someone could tell me exactly how to code it to work with tough also. Thanks

Here is the link of how I got the code to the click and the click on a computer works fine: [Collapse jquery tab when click outside of the div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15352515/collapse-jquery-tab-when-click-outside-of-the-div/28290345?noredirect=1#comment44934742_28290345)

Comment: is it the trigger function that is not working..??

Comment: Basically if I'm on a computer I can click and it works, but if I'm on an iPad it wont work I guess because the code is designed for click not touch. I have researched and can see I need to maybe implement 'click touchstart' but I cant figure out how to get it to work with the code in my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this might help u mate.. :)

```
$(document).on('click touchstart', '#tabs ul li.ui-state-active a',  function(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    alert('clicked');
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much for helping. Still unfortunately not working though  :(

Comment: Replace `$('#tabs ul li.ui-state-active a').trigger('click');` with `$('#tabs ul li.ui-state-active a').trigger('touchstart');`

Comment: Still only works when clicking on a computer, wont work on iPad still.

Comment: Here is a link to what Im trying to get working with the touch http://jsfiddle.net/benopp/8cs7dczn/